# MiKTex on Windows 10

Tags: windows

I have just downloaded and installed MiKTeX. 
When I tried to update from nearest package repository I get 
"Sorry, but something went wrong: The remote package repository is not online. You have to chose another repository.
http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/"

When I tried again using option "let me choose..."
I get no list of repositorys.

On first use I get the error message below.

Any ideas how I can move forward?

```
2015-11-25 19:09:19,819Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:09:19,831Z INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory ("C:\Users\Ben Terrell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2015-11-25 19:09:19,831Z INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory ("C:\Users\Ben Terrell\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2015-11-25 19:09:19,832Z INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-11-25 19:09:19,867Z INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2015-11-25 19:09:21,994Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:09:22,032Z INFO  initexmf - Making format links...
2015-11-25 19:09:23,026Z INFO  initexmf - Making script links...
2015-11-25 19:09:23,556Z INFO  initexmf -   C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-taskbar-icon.exe
2015-11-25 19:09:24,194Z INFO  initexmf -   C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin\miktex-update.exe
2015-11-25 19:09:24,881Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:09:24,895Z INFO  initexmf - Creating language.dat, language.dat.lua and language.def...
2015-11-25 19:09:24,958Z INFO  initexmf - running: mkfntmap --verbose --admin
2015-11-25 19:10:41,681Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:10:41,772Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:10:41,870Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:10:41,883Z INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory ("C:\Users\Ben Terrell\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2015-11-25 19:10:41,883Z INFO  initexmf - Skipping user root directory ("C:\Users\Ben Terrell\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9")...
2015-11-25 19:10:41,884Z INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory (C:\ProgramData\MiKTeX\2.9)...
2015-11-25 19:10:41,906Z INFO  initexmf - Creating fndb for common root directory ("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9")...
2015-11-25 19:10:43,937Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:10:44,026Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 19:10:44,796Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 20:14:36,710Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 20:14:36,710Z FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.

2015-11-25 20:14:36,710Z FATAL initexmf - Info: C:\Users\Ben Terrell\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\d5a1bea1aae2ae396a6df3b9726e48f4.fndb
2015-11-25 20:14:36,710Z FATAL initexmf - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp
2015-11-25 20:14:36,710Z FATAL initexmf - Line: 520
2015-11-25 20:14:36,976Z INFO  initexmf - starting: MiKTeX Configuration Utility 2.9.5700 (MiKTeX 2.9)
2015-11-25 20:14:36,976Z FATAL initexmf - Windows API error 32: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Did you try to synchronize repositories first, via MiKTeX Package Manager (administrator and user modes)?

Comment: The problem is probably not on your end. I just tried on my PC and got same error, and I updated yesterday with no problem.

Comment: so I did synch, and that did not have the desired impact. I will wait 'til tomorrow

Comment: Miktex seems not to be online currently.

Comment: I've update just one hour ago without problems. I'm also using windows 10.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue was solved one day later (server now online).